# Тесты не компилируются. Ошибка "Недопустимый символ"

Tags: юнит-тесты, asp.net-core

Проект на ASP.NET CORE MVC, VS2017.
При компиляции сборки с тестами возникает ошибка:
Ошибка  CS1056  Недопустимый символ "�". Если открыть файл с ошибкой, то видно сгенирированный таким образом файл.
[image: Ссылается на этот файл с ошибкой]
Есть идеи?

Comment: Нажмите на проект, выберите "очистить -> пересобрать", убедитесь что в вашем файле нет скрытых символов.

Comment: // <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated. </auto-generated>
using System;
class AutoGeneratedProgram {static void Main(string[] args){}}

Так выглядит файл если смотреть скажем из far. Но при компиляции не может прочесть адекватно и выдаёт эту ошибку. 
Чистился, нугеты очищал, пересобирался - пока никак.

Answer (score -2):

Причину ошибки так и не установил. Но помогла полная очистка проекта:

```
git clean -xfd
```